# Regex to get value after =

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get the values `ad.test.com` and `768` from the string `"adress=ad.test.com\n port=768"` with this regex but it doesn't work :/

```
$res = preg_split("/^adresse=([a-z]).*port=([0-9]{3})/", $test) ;
```

Comment: `[a-z]` does not include `.` and has no quantifier, so...

Comment: match will only tell me if it exists, I actually want to extract the two values in an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should capture the 2 data points you want:

```
^adress=([a-z.]+).*port=([0-9]{3})
```

You also want to use this with `preg_match`, not `preg_split`.

```
preg_match('/^adress=([a-z.]+).*port=([0-9]{3})/s', 'adress=ad.test.com\n port=768', $match);
echo $match[1] . ' ' . $match[2];
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/Ih929

Notes on why your regex failed:

1. Character class missing `.`, and the character class wasn't quantified.
2. `adress` is in your string but you are looking for `addresse` in your regex
3. `.` doesn't match new lines unless the `s` modifier is used.

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/3MSiDh/1/

A more accurate regex that won't require `s` modifier:

```
^adress=([a-z.]+?)\s*port=(\d{3})
```

Demo 2: https://regex101.com/r/3MSiDh/3/

Comment: please, what if my string is ad.office365.com ? in that case it doesn't work :/

Comment: Please don't unaccept the answer for added requirements, it did answer your question. Add `\d` to the character class then you will allow numbers as well.

Comment: I didn't unaccept the answer ! it was unchecked so I clicked again on it, thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

First optimisation, close to your expression:

```
preg_match('/\badress=([a-z\.]*)\s+port=(\d*)/',$string,$matches)
```

It is slightly more generic.  You do not want to match on 'badaddress' for example, that is what the \b is for, you might get more than 3 digits for the port, etc, I use \d in stead of [0-9].

But this regular expression is very strict on the input: the order is fixed, the location of spaces is limited, you can't have any unknowns.
To resolve that, I would match on parameter/value pairs, and then act upon each of these pairs.  Further, named matching reduces mistakes with parentheses and future evolutions of the regular expression.

The parameter/value pair match can look like this:

```
preg_match_all('/\b(?P<param>[^\d\s]\S*)\s*=\s*(?P<value>\S*)(?:\s|$)/m',$string,$matches)
```

This provides `$matches['param']` and `$matches['value']`.  The example below then walks through this list to find the known parameters and check the validity of their values in order to provide some error messages when appropriate.

The code below shows complete code with some test strings.  You can check it out [here](https://3v4l.org/WWUdJ#output).

```
/** Some strings to test our code */
$testStrings=[
    "adress=example.com port=464",
    "adress =example.com\nport=4645",
    "port=1  protocol=https adress= example.com",
];
/** Test for each string */
foreach($testStrings as $string) {
    print "\n\nTESTING:'".escapeshellarg($string)."'\n";

    /** First method - does not match them all */
    if(preg_match('/\badress=([a-z\.]*)\s+port=(\d*)/',$string,$matches)) {
        print "Matched {$matches[1]}:{$matches[2]}\n";
    }

    /** Second method - get param/value pairs first, then check them */
    if(preg_match_all('/\b(?P<param>[^\d\s]\S*)\s*=\s*(?P<value>\S*)(?:\s|$)/m',$string,$matches)) {
        //var_dump($matches); // Uncomment to see the raw data.
        $i=0;  // We need an index.
        foreach($matches['param'] as $param) {
            $value=$matches['value'][$i]; // Put value in local $value
            $i++;
            switch($param) { // Find parameters we know, complain if needed.
                case "adress":
                    print "ADDRESS IS $value\n";
                    break;
                case "port":
                    if(($result=preg_match('/^\d{3}$/',$value))) {
                        var_dump($result);
                        print "PORT IS $value\n";
                    } else {
                        print "PORT MUST HAVE EXACTLY 3 DIGITS - Got: $value\n";
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    print "UNKNOWN PARAMETER $param=$value\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```